# Showing access denied for the users created with auth_pam plugin(Percona pam for mysql)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, pam

I have installed the percona pam for mysql plugin in my mysql sever. I am using a ubuntu 12.04 OS. Created users using the following commands:

```
CREATE USER 'apuser'@'%'IDENTIFIED WITH auth_pam;
CREATE USER 'apuser'@'localhost'IDENTIFIED WITH auth_pam;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO apuser'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO apuser'@'localhost';
```

I have changed the my.cnf to load the plugin and also created a PAM configuration file mysql as per the documentation of configuring percona pam for mysql.

Still I am not able to login to my mysql with the login credentials apuser to it.

It is showing access denied to apuser@localhost.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds you can run query with other login. 
please run "select user, host, plugin from mysql.user;" .
User 'apuser' should appear with 'auth_pam' in plugin column.

PAM provides the external authentication which enables mysql to accept connections defined outside mysql. It uses your other credentials like unix password or active directory credentials to authenticate mysql login . Hence any user other then the one used to login machine wont be able to login mysql. You must create user with name which is same to login your machine. Now you can access mysql with login-password of machine. 
Hope it helps you.

Thanks.